# TopLink not saving

Tags: toplink

We are using TopLink 9.0.3.7 in our Java application.  I have recently added two new tables I am trying to save to.  I am comparing this to some similar tables that save correctly and everything appears to be the same.  I have compared the descriptors created by TopLink Mappling WorkBench 9.0.3.5 and they appear the same too.

From our Action class

```
submissionDao.transaction(sessionInfo.getClerkReviewSubmission(),
    new TransactionBlock<ClerkReviewSubmission>() {
        public void merge(ClerkReviewSubmission detached,
                ClerkReviewSubmission managed) {

            ClerkReviewTask task = mergeTask(new ClerkReviewTask(),
                    myForm);
            for(ClerkReviewCase crCase: sessionInfo.getClerkReviewSubmission().getCases()){
                createCaseTask(crCase, task);
        }
        }
    });

        private final ClerkReviewCaseTask createCaseTask(ClerkReviewCase crCase,
                ClerkReviewTask task) {
            ClerkReviewCaseTask caseTask = new ClerkReviewCaseTask();
            caseTask.setClerkReviewCase(crCase);
            caseTask.setTask(task);
            crCase.getCaseTasks().add(caseTask);
            task.getCaseTasks().add(caseTask);
            return caseTask;
    }
```

From our BaseDAO class

```
public T transaction(T detached, TransactionBlock transactionBlock) throws BadDBConnection {
    Session session = centralSourceInjector.inject();
    UnitOfWork uow = session.acquireUnitOfWork();

    try {
        T managed = (T)uow.registerObject((T) detached);
        transactionBlock.merge(detached, managed);

        uow.commit();
        session.refreshObject(detached);
        return managed;
    } catch(OptimisticLockException ole){
        uow.rollbackTransaction();
        throw ole;
    } finally {
        uow.release();
    }
}
```

When I debug I am reaching into the BaseDAO class and all I see in the logs are:

UnitOfWork(3889394)--begin unit of work commit
ClientSession(5022219)--Connection(7034305)--begin transaction
ClientSession(5022219)--Connection(7034305)--commit transaction
UnitOfWork(3889394)--end unit of work commit
UnitOfWork(3889394)--release unit of work

Any Suggestions or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker reviewed my code and suggested I add one additional line and it fixed the problem.  He suggested a small change in my Action class:

```
submissionDao.transaction(sessionInfo.getClerkReviewSubmission(),
        new TransactionBlock<ClerkReviewSubmission>() {
            public void merge(ClerkReviewSubmission detached,
                    ClerkReviewSubmission managed) {
                ClerkReviewTask task = mergeTask(new ClerkReviewTask(),
                        myForm);
                for (ClerkReviewCase crCase : sessionInfo
                        .getClerkReviewSubmission().getCases()) {
                    ClerkReviewCase crCase2 = managed.findCase(crCase
                            .getIcisCaseId());
                    createCaseTask(crCase2, task);
                }
            }
        });
}
```